# Why tomcat8 NIO connector doesn't have any action to some tcp connection in 20 seconds?

Tags: tomcat, nio, blocking, nonblocking

I'm using JMeter 2.13's HttpClient4 to send post request to upload 2MByte file to my Tomcat8 web app. Also, the httpclient.cps is set as 128000(1Mb/s) to simulate slow network and there is a ConstantThroughputTimer to control the throughput.The throughput is about 15 request per second.

After several minutes(could be 10,15,etc) there are some socket timeout. From the  pcap file
(http://sabercathost.com/35MD/tcpTimeout.pcap), I see that the whole file is almost done(the whole file's size is 2097152 bytes) but the client just do nothing within 20 seconds which is the timeout setting of tomcat connection.

What could be the reason?
Is it the ConstantThroughtputTimer's scheduler? JVM thread scheduler?
Or HttpClient4?

Edit: I just compared the last packet sent from the client to other pcap that got 200OK and I see no difference -- both are ended with the multipart boundary except that the success one got response from the server. Now I think this is the web app's issue.

Edit: As I suspect this issue is caused by Tomcat8's  NIOConnector I change the connector to BlockingIO and now it works perfectly, no time out. Also after the server side receive the chunk of the file it begins to 
write to the NFS file system, when using NIO the IOWait is like mostly very low(close to 0%) and then burst to 10%, now with BIO the IOWait is constant.

As I mentioned above, server side received whole file but sometimes it haven't replied 200OK forever. From JVisualVM I don't see anything blocked. Hard to say it is NIOConnector or the web app.